# how to get button by refs on ext javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have 2 javascript files. The first file has `finish button` that was initialised by refs and I need to get this button on second file by refs.

**first.js**

```
{
    ref: 'finishButton',
    selector: 'wizard button[id=finishButton]'
}
...
init: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.listen({
            component: {
                'portfoliowizard button[id=finishButton]': {
                click: me.myFunctionForButton
            }
        }
    });
},
myFunctionForButton : function(){
    ...
    this.getFinishButton(); //is worked
    ...
}
```

In second javascript file I have similar code but I don't have the button and I don't know how to create init function, button need for set status enabled or disabled. How do I get button in second file?

```
refs: [
    {
        ref: 'wizard',
        selector: 'wizard'
    },
    {
        ref: 'finishButton',
        selector: 'wizard button[id=finishButton]'
    }
]

mySecondFunciton : function(){
    ...
    this.getFinishButton(); //getFinishButton is not a function
    ...
}
```

Comment: version of Ext? What kind of class contain the refs? You can't post a class and not explain which class it's extending

Comment: I use Ext version 4,

Comment: You still didn't say what class you're extending

Comment: @JuanMendes, the _first_ file extend `extend: 'Ext.app.Controller 'name.WizardView'` and _second_ file `extend: 'Ext.app.Controller'`

Comment: You still don't have enough information. Post should contain code that we could paste somewhere and have it work. You are not showing how `mySecondFunciton` is called. My guess is that `this` does not point to the controller in that case. But again, you need to improve your question. Please see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that at the time the refs are resolved for the second controller, `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("wizard button[id=finishButton]")` is null or undefined; while at the time the refs are resolved for the first controller, `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("wizard button[id=finishButton]")` returns the component.

You could try to hack around it like this:

```
MyApp.app.getController("First").getFinishButton()
```

or you could try to find when the controller refs are resolved and how to change the dependency tree such that the component resolves correctly.

Comment: The error says that `getFinishButton` is not a function, not that its return is undefined. And you are right that what you are suggesting is a hack :) it would work, but I would never pass a code review that works around a problem without understanding its root cause.

Comment: Well, `getFinishButton` is not a function if there is no component that matches the ref selector at the time the refs are resolved.

Comment: No, that's not true, it returns null if the selector doesn't match anything but the function does exist. See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1284

Comment: Thanks, this is helped me.